# Wp Ajax search lite add custom database table

Tags: wordpress, search, redirection-wordpress-plugin

I am using Ajax search lite on my website but I have two custom datables with special data. I want to add those to the query of the Ajax search lite plugin. These are not custom post types or fields!

How can I add those data tables to the queries?